# Missing header files for VTK

Tags: visual-studio, vtk

I installed `Visual Studio 2010`, `Qt` and `Cmake`. I configured them. Then I wanted to test by an example code. However, the program cannot find the header files. I searched on the internet and found that there might be a problem with the `PATH`.

Then, I followed this way that results in failure:

I wrote each folder name separately by putting semicolon between them to

> Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories.

In this way, program found the header files but it gave me an `error LNK1104`. I think it happened because the Path for file name expands to more than 260 characters. I learned that from [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

I tried to find one folder that I can write to `PATH`. I think it's lib file. But I could not find it.

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: If you are using CMake you should never ever need to mess with Additional Include directories directly. You set you include directories in the CMakeLists.txt file you create for your application.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm newbie here. Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: Can you post the CMakeLists.txt file for your application? Or are you not using CMake to generate the project file for your application.

Comment: BTW, Examples of a CMakeLists.txt for a vtk application can be found in the wiki examples. Here is 1 link: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/ShareCameraBetweenQVTKWidgets

Comment: Actually I confuse the locations of some files while installing programs. But as I remember, there was no file called CMakeLists.txt in project file. I'll let you know what'll happen after installations.

Comment: This file would have been something that you intentionally created instead of using visual studio to create your project. It is obvious that you are not using CMake for your project. Can you post the linker errors then? What you need to do is to add additional libraries to your link tab since you are not having CMake do this for you.

Comment: @TahaYusuf did you get this resolved following drescherjm's suggestions? If so, please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Setting two values in visual studio will remove this error.

1. Go to Properties of the project -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Set the correct value for "Additional Options".
2. Go to Properties of the project -> Linker -> Input -> Set correct the value for "Additional Dependencies".

If you create the project using CMake, then these values will be setup automatically.